# Query a Datagridview.Rows or Dataset using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview, linq-to-dataset

I have some problem. Since I'm not so experienced with Linq I couldn't figure out how to query my datagridview (or directly to dataset preferably) and show results on another datagridview.

This is where I fill my full datagridview and dataset:

```
string icerikQuery = "SELECT * FROM [RRSelfServis].[dbo].[talimaticerikler] order by [kod] ASC, [percent] DESC";
//MessageBox.Show(icerikQuery);

SqlDataAdapter icerikadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(icerikQuery, connection);
DataSet icerikSet = new DataSet();
icerikadapter.Fill(icerikSet, "Test_table_icerik");
dataGridView2.DataSource = icerikSet;
dataGridView2.DataMember = "Test_table_icerik";
```

And here is my query part:

```
dataGridView4.DataSource = from DataGridViewRow in dataGridView2.Rows
                              where rowView.Row.Field<string>("kod").Value.ToString() == SomeSearchStringVariable
                              orderby rowView.Row.Field<decimal>("percent") descending
                              select row;
```

But currently I'm having error for `dataGridView2.Rows`:

> Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection'. 'Where' not found.
>   Consider explicitly specifying the type of the range variable
>   'DataGridViewRow'.

My first choice would be to query DataSet `icerikSet` but datagridview would work too.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the DataTable from the DataSet you want to search, mark it as enumerable and select the rows matching your search.

```
var query = from row in icerikSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
            where row.Field<string>("kod").Equals(SomeSearchStringVariable)
            orderby row.Field<decimal>("percent") descending
            select row;
```

You can create another DataSet or DataTable from the query and set it as a source for your grid.

```
DataTable dt = query.CopyToDataTable();
[...]
```

Comment: Great. I was able to implement this wish some little modification and worked like a charm. Thanks.